# Make pseudo classes work in MPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

MPDF is a PHP class that converts html to pdf http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php 
This doesn't work in mpdf:

HTML:

```
<div class="fillme"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.fillme:after {
    content: 'Here I am, filling you oh div'
}
```

The text "Here I am, filling you oh div" doesn't appear in the pdf generated. I'd be grateful if you helped me to get it working. This html/css is completely compliant IE 8 +, so I'm surprised the popular MPDF doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply impossible to do this. Wait for an update, but in the meantime, try to mock effects such as underlinings with transparent divs with border bottoms.